# Trying to only awk count unique results from a column rather than count each line -

Tags: bash

I have a script that works to grab each line from files and lists the count, but what I also want is to grab only the unique instances from column 3. For example the lines say things like in the pic below, and while my current script counts all instances of COMM_CONT, that I really want is for it to count the unique lines that feature COMM_CONT, which for the pic would be 2.

[image]

So what I want it to have the below script count the unique number of the times the four patterns happen. I feel like it should be an easy fix, but I keep trying the -u and -uniq and I can't seem to get it to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
ORAL_MICRO=$(awk -F ',' '/ORAL_MICRO/{print $3;}' $1 | wc -l)
LAB_CONT=$(awk -F ',' '/LAB_CONT/{print $3;}' $1 | wc -l)
COMM_CONT=$(awk -F ',' '/COMM_CONT/{print $3;}' $1 | wc -l)
IMMUNE=$(awk -F ',' '/IMMUNE/{print $3;}' $1 | wc -l)
echo $1, $ORAL_MICRO, $LAB_CONT, $COMM_CONT, $IMMUNE >> $2
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. That way, we can actually _use_ the data you show us to test our answers.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways spring to mind:

1. use `sort` to get the unique lines:

   ```bsh
   COMM_CONT=$(awk -F ',' '/COMM_CONT/{print $3;}' $1 | sort -u | wc -l)
   ```
2. do the work in awk

   ```bsh
   COMM_CONT=$(awk -F, '
       $3 ~ /COMM_CONT/ && !($3 in seen) {seen[$3]=1; count++}
       END {print count}
   ' $1)
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This worked a treat!